# Function environment in R

Tags: r, function, environment

I have the below code for understanding the complex environment layers:

```
depositor <- function() {
  balance <- 0
  function(amount) {
   balance <<- balance + amount # assign in the parent
    return(balance) 
  } 
}
deposit <- depositor()
deposit(100)
100
deposit(32)
132
```

Could you please explain me how the above code works in terms of environment?

I do not understand from the line `deposit <- depositor()`

Thank you guys!

Comment: `depositor` returns a function.  This function takes a number as the input and remember and return the cumulative sum of the numbers received so far.

Comment: This is a function within a function. The return object of `depositor()` is a function, which is why `deposit(100)` works. My advice would be to ignore the source where you found this as this is not the "proper" R way of doing things.

Comment: Another interesting experiment would be to make another function by `deposit2 <- depositor()`.  Does this function start from 0 or 132?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Of course closures are a proper R way. See the scoping demo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyhole to understanding this example is `depositor()`
It will return

```
depositor()

function(amount) {
   balance <<- balance + amount # assign in the parent
    return(balance) 
  }
<environment: 0x8936fb0>
```

That part is somewhat straightforward. The last complete block inside the outer function `depositor()` is  the definition of an anonymous function `function(amount)`  . So it is this function which becomes the return value of the outer function, just like any ordinary variable would have had. The scope of both `balance` and this anonymous function are limited to the outer function, i.e., `depositor`, and none of them can be directly accessed from outside.

However, the anonymous function thus returned can be stored and reused in the parent frame (global environment).

```
 environment(fun = depositor)
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
 environment(fun = deposit)
# <environment: 0x8a3f5a8>
parent.env(  environment(fun = deposit) )
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

`deposit <- depositor()` stores this retuned  function in a var named deposit, and it can be accessed through it `deposit(amountvalue)`

The scope of `amount` is still limited to the inner function. There is no way to pass the value of `amount` to it through the outer function as it not assigned  anywhere else. That can only be done through the saved proxy `deposit(100)`

---

Edit: I revisited my answer and found I had left out the most interesting part of this exercise. Why does the value of `balance` persist from one call to another? i.e., why does the next call not reset the value of balance to 0? 
Every new call to `depositor()` (**not deposit!**) will return a function with its own parent/enclosing environment. Here's the proof:It's also suggested in a comment above by @Kota Mori:

```
deposit<- depositor()
x<- depositor()

#following will have two different values
environment(deposit)
environment(x) 
# and they will work independently
x(100); x(20)
deposit(100);deposit(1000)
```

This is the crux of `closure`,  a topic on which I have little to offer. A call to the inner function `i.e., x() or deposit()`  will not meddle with the environment associated with previous call, because the parent function itself will not be called, only the inner function will be. In this case the inner function also updates balance in its respective enclosing environment through the `<<-` assignment, thus persisting the value from one call to next

---

Another thing can be , why does a variable returned from a function not come with similar enclosure? It's because as per documentation of `function` --  `the value of the last evaluated expression is returned.`